# Lightning Storm Bug?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've discovered a possible bug after making my Destruction skill legendary; Lightning Storm doesn't make progress towards my destruction skill! I've used Blizzard, Fire Storm, Incinerate, Icy Spear, and even Thunderbolt, and they all worked and made the skill increase. Does anyone know how or why this bug could've occurred/how I can make more use of my favorite way to kill things?

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known bug](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lightning_Storm) that using the Lighting Storm Destruction magic will not grant you experience points towards your Destruction tree. You will need to use other types of magic to level your destructive abilities.

This bug, and countless others, are fixed in the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Unofficial_Skyrim_Patch).